# I18n row/column data in sqlite3 table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

I am trying to translate the collection_select data but not modify the actual data in the database table PayType

This is the relevant order form html.erb

_form.html.erb

```
<%= f.label :pay_type_id, t('.pay_type') %><br />
<%= collection_select(:order, :pay_type_id, PayType.all, :name, :name) %>
```

This is the relevant db schema

```
create_table "orders", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.text     "address"
  t.string   "email"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.integer  "pay_type_id"
  t.datetime "ship_date"
end

create_table "pay_types", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

I cannot figure this out, I have tried to translate the name but get a no method error. I know how to add a locale column that will only display if I choose display rows with a locale of 'es' but I would like to superficially translate the names without changing the actual db values.

What would I as far as noting t('.xxx') and how would I call that in the en.yml and es.yml?

Also if youre curious the names in the db are:
Check
Credit Card
Purchase Order

Any guidance is appriciated, its driving me mad.

Comment: yah, don't use sqlite, you are much better off installing postgresql locally and using that, especially when you need to test the full feature set. sqlite is only for toy projects.

Comment: Whether I use SQLite3 or PostgreSQL wouldn't the code in Ruby/ect. to translate the string data itself be the same (since I'm just trying to show a Spanish use my Spanish translation of the value in the database)?

Comment: It looks like you are playing around with internationalization, including Unicode and i8 support, which is fully supported in Postgres. It's probably poorly supported if at all in SQLLite. Personally, I would upgrade to postgres, if the problem still occurred, I'd then think more carefully about it.